# Conditional formatting custom formula to colorize QUERY results

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

When I use QUERY() and rows of results are returned, I would like to have conditional formatting so that I can see which cells I shouldn't edit because they are produced by a formula. I currently use ISFORMULA(A1) to identify cells that have a formula in them. I would also like to format the cells filled with the results of my QUERY().

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

results of QUERY as an endpoint are undifferentiable from standard manual input so the only thing you can do is to run QUERY within conditional formatting like for example:

```
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH(A1; TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; QUERY($A:$B; "select B where A is not null"; ))))
```

Comment: This is the information I was looking for. Unfortunate that I can't just conditionally format the whole page to show what content is query output. Thank you.